# React modal with delete functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, frontend

I have an app which shows a list of items in rows. Every item has a corresponding delete button. When I click it, it shows a modal with confirmation. When I click 'cancel', the action is canceled. When I click 'confirm' the modal do as follows:
1. It displays a loading icon
2. It changes the style (color and text - now it says it is done)
3. It removes the item

What I get so far is just displaying modal, same as in this article:
https://daveceddia.com/open-modal-in-react/
Plus just console logging when confirm is clicked.
How do I implement the feature?
Do I need to use Redux? Or is there some kind of library for confirmation dialogs?

My code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/6n03myqw8w

Comment: No you don't need redux for this, you can have a function that runs when you hit okay on Modal confirmation that will delete the record.

Comment: I was thinking something like this:
`approveModal = () => {
    console.log('deleting'); // load icon, then change modal style, then delete item
  };
`

But how to implement that?

Comment: @n3stle can you post your code?

Comment: @n3stle post your code, preferably on https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: already in the post, will do the same in codesandbox

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example without using Redux. It shows how to use components to get around the issue of having to rely on a data store. The main container holds the data and actions and we simply pass these actions and the necessary data to remove and display a modal.

Now this doesn't account for the loading and style changes but you can bind these to the actions within the MockModal class to add a fake loading icon (since we're using data from a container, the data is instant). The style change could be added to the `removeTask` method in MockModal, or you can look into an animation technique to enhance the UI. The below is purely a functional implementation.

Let me know if you need more help.

```js
class MockModal extends React.Component {
  removeTask = () => this.props.removeTask(this.props.data);
  closeModal = () => this.props.closeModal();
  render() {
    const { id, name } = this.props.data;
    if (this.props.displayModal) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h5>You want to delete task {id} : {name}</h5>
          <button onClick={this.removeTask}>Confirm</button>
          <button onClick={this.closeModal}>Close</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
    return null;
  }
}

class Task extends React.Component {
  showModal = (task) => this.props.show(this.props.task);
  render() {
    const { id, name } = this.props.task;
    return (
      <div>
        <h5>{id}:{name}</h5>
        <button onClick={this.showModal}>(REMOVE)</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showModal: false,
    modal: {
      id: null,
      name: null,
    },
    tasks: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Star Wars' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Harry Potter' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Lord of the Rings' },
    ],
  }
  showModal = (task) => this.setState({ modal: task, showModal: true, });
  hideModal = () => this.setState({ showModal: false, });
  removeTask = (activeTask) => {
    const index = this.state.tasks.findIndex(task => {
      return task.id === activeTask.id;
    });
    this.setState({
      showModal: false,
      tasks: [
        ...this.state.tasks.slice(0, index),
        ...this.state.tasks.slice(index + 1),
      ]
    })
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <MockModal 
          displayModal={this.state.showModal}
          closeModal={this.hideModal}          
          removeTask={this.removeTask}
          data={this.state.modal} 
        />
        {this.state.tasks.map(task => {
          return (
            <Task key={task.id} task={task} show={this.showModal} />
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: There is a bug in your app. If you remove the second item first it removes the third one as well.

Comment: @Win yep, there is a bug, can you help me fix it? I tried doing something with `slice` but to no avail

Comment: @n3stle Sorry, I typed splice instead of slice. All fixed.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to use Redux?

No, definitely not

> How do I implement the feature? [...] Or is there some kind of library for confirmation dialogs?

Sounds like you're already there. Instead of `console.log()` on confirm, do the thing! By "the thing" I'm referring to something along the lines of this...

```
handleConfirm = () => {
  this.setState({loading: true}); // show loading icon
  deleteItem(id)
    .then(() => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false, // hide loading icon
        success: true, // show colored success text
      });
    }
    .catch((err) => {
      // handle delete error here
    }

}
```

Your render function would then look something like this...

```
render() {
  const { loading, success } = this.state;
  return (
    {loading && <Loading />}
    {success && <SuccessMessage />}
    {!loading && !success && <ConfirmMessageWithButtons />}
  )
}
```

UPDATE: I see that you've provided code on code sandbox now, so here's a kludgy solution using your code. It's kludgy because it's simulating async operations using setTimeouts

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Modal from './components/Modal';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
      isOpen: false,
      loading: false,
      success: false, 
    };
  }

  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen,
    });
  };

  approveModal = () => {
    this.setState({loading: true });
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ 
      loading: false,
      success: true 
    }), 1000)
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ 
      isOpen: false 
    }), 3000)
  };

  render() {
    const { loading, success } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {!success && !loading && <p>Item to delete</p>}
        <button onClick={this.toggleModal}>Delete</button>

        <Modal show={this.state.isOpen} onApprove={this.approveModal} onClose={this.toggleModal}>
          {loading && "Loading..."}
          {success && "Success (make me green)"}
          {!success && !loading && "Here's some text for the modal"}
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here's a link https://codesandbox.io/s/10o12zzk63