# React - Modal with Confirm Deletion from array map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building an app displaying lists of items in an array using ES6 `map`. Each item in the array contains a text and a "remove" button. Clicking the "remove" button will remove the item from the array based on the item id. This is triggered with reducer dispatch inside function connected with and contextAPI.

Here's a basic code that works:

```js
import React, { useState, useContext} from "react";

//context
import { ListsContext } from "./listsContext";

function Lists() {
  const { items, dispatch } = useContext(ListsContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Lists</h1>
      {items.length ? (
        items.map(item => (
          <div>
            <ListTag
              key={item.id}
              item={item}
              remove={() => dispatch({ type: "REMOVE", id: item.id });}
            />
          </div>
        ))
      ) : (
        <p> No Categories, Insert a category </p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function ListTag({ item, edit, confirm }) {
  return (
    <div className="list-tag">
      <div className="list-info">
        <p>{item.description}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="config-btn">
        <button onClick={remove}>Remove</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


export default Lists;
```

The code above will remove the item from the array immediately after "remove" button is clicked. My goal is to have a modal popup when "remove" button is clicked, confirming the deletion with a message, something similar to  [Modal confirmation #1 - codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kx6yx12l1r?fontsize=14) or [Modal confirmation #2 by Chris Geirman - codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/10o12zzk63?fontsize=14). For more information view [Stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46838227/6387458).

Unfortunately, the linked examples do not use react-hooks, reducers, or contextAPI. I have tried a similar approach and I am very close to a solution.  After clicking the item "remove" button, a modal pops up with delete confirmation message and two buttons underneath it (remove & cancel). Unfortunately, clicking the modal "remove" button does not delete the correct item based on the item id. For example, if there are four items in the array, removing the first item which is on top the of the array ("Array One") will end up deleting the item at the bottom ("Array Four"). To understand what is happening better, look at the example in my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-architecture-5xn3h?fontsize=14).

I am struggling to find a solution for deleting a specific item by id using the popup modal. What did I do wrong? Any solutions, recommendation or better suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily resolved when you consider that you only need *one* modal returned from `Lists` instead of having a modal attached to each list item. When a list item is clicked you can add the selected item to state and use that in the modal:

```
function Lists() {

  const { items, dispatch } = useContext(ListsContext);

  // Store the selected item instead
  const [ selectedItem, setSelectedItem ] = useState();

  const deleteItem = item => {

    // Make sure your type and your reduce case label match
    dispatch({ type: "REMOVE_CATEGORY", id: item.id });
    setSelectedItem();
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <h1>Lists</h1>
        {items.length ? (
          items.map(item => (
            <div>
              <ListTag
                key={item.id}
                item={item}
                confirm={() => setSelectedItem(item)}
              />
            </div>
          ))
        ) : (
          <p> No Categories, Insert a category </p>
        )}
      </div>

      // Confirm is now at the end of the list
      // We pass in the selected item
      <Confirm
        item={selectedItem}
        remove={deleteItem}
        cancel={() => setSelectedItem(false)}
      />
    </Fragment>
);
}

function ListTag({ item, edit, confirm }) {
  return (
    <div className="list-tag">
      <div className="list-info">
        <p>{item.description}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="config-btn">
        <button onClick={confirm}>Remove</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Confirm({ cancel, item, remove }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {item && (
        <Modal>
          <p>
            You are about to permanently delete <strong>{item.name}</strong>{" "}
            category. Are you sure you want to do this?
          </p>
          <button onClick={() => remove(item)}>Remove</button>
          <button onClick={cancel}>cancel</button>
        </Modal>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-nightingale-pl91x)

Comment: Modal attached on each items in array. Now I see the problem It now become more clear.  Also, approach to activate modem by `item` instead of `confirm` state. Thank you very much, I truly appreciate it.